# TypeScript and Vue class - TS7053 index signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Vue 2.6 with vue class component (and typescript).

Actual code:

```
private validateField(fieldType: string, e: string) {
  this[fieldType] = e.length > 0
}
```

Gives an error:

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Index'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Index'.

What's a recommended way to add signatures in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is create an indexer interface:

```
interface ILookup<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

And then make the Vue class implement this interface:

```
export default class App extends Vue implements ILookup<any> { 

    [index: string]: any;

    private validateField(fieldType: string, e: string) {
        this[fieldType] = e.length > 0
    }
}
```

We have to use an `any` as type parameter because Vue internally uses all kinds of different types which can be indexed on you component object. So for example when we use a `boolean` as type parameter:

```
interface ILookup<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

export default class App extends Vue implements ILookup<boolean> { 

    [index: string]: boolean;

    private validateField(fieldType: string, e: string) {
        this[fieldType] = e.length > 0
    }
}
```

we get the following (and other) compilation errors:

> TS2411: Property '$attrs' of type 'Record' is not
>   assignable to string index type 'boolean'.

and:

> TS2411: Property '$children' of type 'Vue[]' is not assignable to
>   string index type 'boolean'.

Comment: It's the same as `(this as any)[fieldType]`?

Comment: No it's not the same I would say. Because by using `(this as any)[fieldType]` you cast your whole component to an `any` where in my example I only declare the return type of the indexer to be `any`. I updated my answer with some more info.